# error in kibana login after xpack enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am running 7.6.1 ES and kibana in Ubuntu server .

once i enabled the xpack security i not able to login to kibana

in ES configuration

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
discovery.type: single-node
```

i used following command to generate pwd

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
```

and kibana configuration added following file

> `elasticsearch.username: "kibana" 
>   elasticsearch.password: "***"`

i able to get login screen but not able to login
please find screen -
[image]

and i can see following error in syslog

```
> Mar  9 11:43:14 vv-es kibana[10782]:
> {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-03-09T11:43:14Z","tags":[],"pid":10782,
> "method":"post","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/internal/security/login","method":"post",
> "headers":{"x-forwarded-for":"49.206.240.190","x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-forwarded-port":"443","host":"dnshost.net",
> "x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-5e662bd2-a051372e02673d70baaadc8a","content-length":"56","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache","accept":"application/json,
> text/plain,
> */*","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","kbn-version":"7.6.1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0
> (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/80.0.3987.132
> Safari/537.36","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8", 
> "origin":"https://dnshost.net","sec-fetch-site":"same-origin","sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
> "referer":"https://dnshost.net/login?next=%2Fapp%2Fkibana","accept-encoding":"gzip,
> deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8"}, 
> "remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","userAgent":"127.0.0.1","referer":"https://dnshost.net/login?next=%2Fapp%2Fkibana"}  ,"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":63,"contentLength":9},"message":"POST
> /internal/security/login 404 63ms - 9.0B"}
```

any suggestion in this .
Thanks

Comment: Do you use the password generated by kibana ? Why are you using 'elastic' user (showed in your screenshot) and not the 'kibana' user provided by your configuration ?

Comment: yes i used password generated by bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto ,even if kibana user also its same